# comparing 2 arrays of objects and performing a mongodb bulkwrite with the differences

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to compare an array of sub documents with one array being the current version of the subdocuments and a new array which will be sent by the front end to update the current array of subdocuments with the changes. this array of subdocuments is used to generate unique forms in the long term but have made example code to see if it would work. I generate an array of updates to use with the mongodb bulkwrite feature and need to know if all seems dandy in my code. If there is a more efficient way of doing this, I'm all ears.

This code example is the main function that will be called when the user submits the http put request.

```js
const exampleFunction = async () => {
  //create bulkWrite array for mongodb
  //compare if the name has changed
  //compare if the object does not exist so that it may be pushed into template array.

  // EXAMPLE OF PARENT DOCUMENT
  // const parentObj = {
  //   _id: '123',
  //   //array of sub documents of original document that will be used for comparison
  //   formData: [
  //     { _id: 'abc', name: 'Cat' },
  //     { _id: 'def', name: 'Dog' },
  //     { _id: 'ghi', name: 'Bird' }
  //   ]
  // }

  // ID of parent document
  const parentID = '123'

  // Current formData array of sub documents in the parent document
  const oldArray = [
    { _id: 'abc', name: 'Cat' },
    { _id: 'def', name: 'Dog' },
    { _id: 'ghi', name: 'Bird' }
  ] 

  // New array sent from front end to be compared with against the old array
  const newArray = [
    { _id: 'abc', name: 'Cat' },
    {_id: 'def', name: 'Dog' },
    { _id: 'ghi', name: 'Lizard' },
    { name: 'Goat' }
  ]
  
  const update = compareArrays(oldArray, newArray, parentID)
  
  // bulkWrite function made to mongodb
  await collection.bulkWrite(update).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

While this code is the main comparison function that is called in the code block above.

```js
const compareArrays = async (a, b, parentID) => {
  let bulkArray = []

  a.map((itemA) => {
    b.map(async (itemB) => {
      if(!itemB._id) {
        // Check if a new object has been added that has yet to receive ID from database, if no id, then push to array of parent document
        bulkArray.push(
          {
            updateOne: {
              filter: {_id: parentID},
              update: { $push: { formData: itemB } },
            },
          }
        )
      } else {
        if(itemA._id === itemB._id) {
          //match ids and perform another check
          if (itemA.name !== itemB.name) {
            //check if the names do not match and push the update to bulkArray for mongodb to update sub document of parent document
            bulkArray.push(
              {
                updateOne: {
                  filter: {_id: parentID, 'formData._id': itemA._id},
                  update: { $set: { name: itemB.name } }
                }
              }
            )
          }
        }
      }
    })
  })

  return bulkArray
}
```

The final document should look something like this,

```js
  const finalParentObj = {
    _id: '123',
    formData: [
      { _id: 'abc', name: 'Cat' },
      { _id: 'def', name: 'Dog' },
      { _id: 'ghi', name: 'Lizzard' },
      { id: 'jkl', name: 'Goat'}
    ]
  }
```

Comment: disadvantage of using bulkwrite is that it doesn`t return document affected by write operations

Answer (score 0):

So the bulkwrite() is used mainly to reduce the number of multiple trips required to write multiple operations. It does all the operations in an atomic way. It takes the input as an array of operations you wanted to perform on the DB.collection

```
db.collection.bulkWrite([
  { updateOne: { filter: { a: 1 }, update: { $set: { a: 2 } } } },
  { updateMany: { filter: { b: 1 }, update: { $set: { b: 2 } } } },
]);
```

Comment: The document isnt needed to be returned when the update is made. Im trying to create a function that compares the old version of the array agaisnt the new version of the array and make update changes on multiple documents with the differences. The bulkwrite is to update multiple documents and to not make 100+ update calls to mongodb using `schema.updateOne()` a bunch of times